# Count query grouping by date ignoring time

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a DATE variable that should be grouped ignoring the time in this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), update_date
FROM table1
HAVING count(update_date)>1
GROUP BY update_date
ORDER BY update_date desc
```

The result is right but I need to group them by the DAY and not by seconds since the date format of the field is DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.  I would like to compare only the DD/MM/YYYY, ignoring the time of the update, by day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`trunc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151) to set the time part to `00:00:00`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), trunc(update_date) as update_date
FROM table1
GROUP BY trunc(update_date)
HAVING count(trunc(update_date))>1
ORDER BY trunc(update_date) desc
```

Comment: should `group by` be before `having`?

Comment: @vkp: it actually doesn't matter: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF20040 but putting the having after the group by "looks" better

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name..got it..i didn't know this before..thanks